# Can financial accounts be imported?

Tags: civicontribute, import

I have close to 100 financial accounts from Quickbooks that I need to get in CiviCRM. I'd like to avoid entering these by hand. Is there any way I could import these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are likely more tables involved that just that table so I would not go directly into the database. There is an api for creating financial accounts so you could try using the [csvimporter extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) to import them. I believe it is available as a downloadable extension from your manage extensions page.

I would suggest just importing one and then looking to make sure it looks correct before doing more. Not that there are at least 3 entities involved - financial types, financial accounts & the one that links them.

Financial accounts have the cost code information and financial types are what the user selects. Each Financial type should have a number of related financial accounts for different purposes (income, expense etc) - so just look to make sure they look the same through the UI before you go for 100 imports